# Minimum Sufficient Statistic for Uniform(θ,θ+1) distribution?

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

I saw that (min(X), max(X)) are minimal sufficient statistic for this.

But I was wondering, why can't we just have min(X) OR max(X)?

If distribution is Uniform(θ1,θ2), then it makes sense to have two dimensional minimum sufficient statistic, but if not then why can't we recover θ from min(X) OR max(X)?

Comment: Because of the constraint $\theta<\min x_i\,,\, \max x_i<\theta+1$, i.e. $\max x_i-1<\theta<\min x_i$ in the joint density.

Comment: @StubbornAtom why would θ < minx?? I guess u meant >. But again why can't we recover θ from min X OR max X?

Comment: It follows from $\theta<x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n<\theta+1$. If you leave out any one of $\min x_i$ or $\max x_i$ you lose information about $\theta$ (because of the constraint), and $\min x_i$ or $\max x_i$ no longer remain minimal sufficient on their own.

Comment: I get why  θ<minxi. But given a data sample, and knowing that it is from Uniform(θ, θ+1), my approximation for θ will be as good from just one statistic, which is: (min(x) + max(x))/2, as from two different statistic. Thus just a single statistic of (min(x) + max(x))/2 should be sufficient to recover θ.